# Changing String input into int in C#

Tags: c#

How to convert the string input taken using Console.ReadLine() function in a C# code??? Suppose I have created 2 integer variables a and b. Now I want to take from user the values of a and b. How can this be performed in C#?

Comment: `int.Parse()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b3h1hf19.aspx. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx):

```
Convert.ToInt32(input);
```

Or [TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx)

```
bool success = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option, that I usually use is [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
int retunedInt;
bool conversionSucceed = int.TryParse("your string", out retunedInt);
```

so it's good fit for fault tollerant pattern like:

```
if(!int.TryParse("your string", out retunedInt)) 
  throw new FormatException("Not well formatted string");
```

Comment: +1. Out of curiosity if you're throwing an exception anyway, why not use int.parse and handle the exception that may throw?

Comment: @keyboardP: 1. You can handle some presice (custom exception you raise) and continue running program 2. You may think to not use exceptino at all, and just handle a flow in some way.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Usually I use `TryParse` for your second reason but I see that a program may have custom exceptions and logging which would be useful. Just making sure I hadn't missed some secret `TryParse` usage :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this (make sure they input valid string):

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Also this:

```
int a;
string input;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();

} while (!int.TryParse(input, out a));
```

Comment: You can also use `int.TryParse` is you are not sure the input is a string and you want to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it with [`Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx);

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.

```
int i;
bool b = Int32.TryParse(yourstring, out i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

> The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse
>   method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It
>   eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a
>   FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be
>   successfully parsed. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use Int32.TryParse to avoid exceptions in case your user doesn't type an integer number

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
int a;
if (Int32.TryParse(userInput, out a))
    Console.WriteLine("You have typed an integer number");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Your text is not an integer number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `int.TryParse` like:

```
int a;
Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter valid number (integer): ");
}

Console.WriteLine("The number entered: {0}", a);
```